# How do I go from 1.4795e+004 to 14795.00?

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I have this problem that has been bothering me for quite a while.. I want to change the format of the number.. Don`t know how? Ive tried the help files but can't find the answer.. If you can help me please do..

Answer (score 8):

There are three different things you could potentially be referring to when you talk about the "format" of a number: the display format, the variable storage format in memory (i.e. the data type/class), and the storage format in a data file. I'll address each...

- **Display format:** As already mentioned by [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480177/how-do-i-go-from-1-4795e004-to-14795-00/1480179#1480179), the display format can be adjusted with the [FORMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) command. However, this only affects how the numbers are *displayed*, not how they are *stored in memory*.
- **Variable types/classes:** There are a number of [numeric classes](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html), both floating point and signed/unsigned integer types, that variables can use. By default, MATLAB variables are stored as double-precision floating point numbers. To convert to other types, you can use the variable type as a function to recast a value. For example, `a = uint8(0);` converts `0` to an 8-bit unsigned integer type and stores it in `a`, while `b = single(pi);` converts the value `pi` into single-precision and stores it in `b`.
- **File storage format:** When reading/writing numeric values to files, the type of file affects how it will be stored. A binary file (written to and read from using [FWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fwrite.html) and [FREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html)) stores the complete binary representation of a number, and can thus represent it as exactly the same type as it is stored in memory as a variable (double-precision, single-precision, 8-bit integer, etc.).

  Alternatively, a text file (written to and read from using [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) and [FSCANF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html), among other functions) will store a value in a string format that you must specify when outputting the values to the file. You can specify the digits of precision, as well as the format (such as exponential notation or hexadecimal). The documentation for [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) specifies these output formats.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [format](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) command

**Example**:

```
format long; pi
   3.141592653589793
format short e; pi
   3.1416e+000
format short g; pi
   3.1416
```

Comment: how much does the format fuction cover.. for example if I have a series of functions that work with each other.. do I have to use it on every function??

Comment: "The format function affects only how numbers are displayed, not how MATLAB computes or saves them." How would I change how it saves them?? is it posible?

Comment: The data is just the data.  An IEEE 8 byte double precision floating point.  I think you're asking how to change the default format maybe?  That is done through the preferences where you can change the default format at the command line:
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-22072.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf('%.2f', 1.4795e4);
```

(in particular: if you want it displayed/saved/printed a certain way, be explicit about it!)