# How to round double to something that a 'normal' human can read. (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

My MATLAB code is giving me following `double` answer: `1.727287951101063e+04`. I know its about 0, but how can I round/convert it into a better readable (long?) number type?

I tried this code:

```
format long
portfolio1.myValue = ((portfolio1.myValue + Gewinn)*10)/10;
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: could you display your actual output and also the expected output? Also, make sure you understand the construct of formatter - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html

Comment: Use `format long g;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I go from 1.4795e+004 to 14795.00?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480177/how-do-i-go-from-1-4795e004-to-14795-00)

Comment: "I know its about 0" - 1e+04 is about 10000.

Answer (score 3):

Use `format long g`:

```
>> A = 1.727287951101063e+04;
>> format long g;
>> A

A =

          17272.8795110106
```

You can check out the docs on how `format` works: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html.  However, `format long g` essentially represents your number with 15 digits, fitting all of the digits that make the significant part of your number (without the decimal place), and filling in the rest of the spots with the decimal numbers (those that follow after the decimal place).